# webpack-dev-server keeps serving old files

Tags: webpack

I'm running webpack-dev-server and it keeps serving old files, any ideas?

I have removed any reference to foo.js in my project

[image]

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "#source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Transpile any JavaScript file:
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at the start of foo.js, do you enter it? If so, what's the call stack?

Comment: I know it's been too long, but I am facing the same issue. Have you solved this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using these options:

```
webpack-dev-server --hot --inline
```

Comment: Doesn't help, it doesn't even generate the bundle, you normally get with running `webpack`

Comment: It doesn't generate the bundle files; it's all in memory. Anyway, try disabling the cache (eg. Chrome has an option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)".